# PHP - Returning JSON from file in the background

Tags: php, rest

I have a problem:

I need to return a server response to a request while redirecting the response back to my html page.

My request runs through following process:

1. POST via HTML form
2. createobject.php gets the information from the POST and calls the method create of the class Object

   $object->create();
3. the method create in object runs the code and returns true of false

   > Here is my problem, I need to send echo **$this->conn->lastInsertId();** as a response to the server
4. createobject.php redirects the request back to the HTML page
5. User sees whether the insert was successful

Step 1 and 5 are for testing only, I need the response in createobject.php

Answer (score 0):

You can passing your response when redirecting to HTML page.
redirect like this.

```
header('Location: http://example.com?json='. urlencode($json));
```

Then access it from HTML page use php or use javascript.

From php you can do like this

```
$data = json_decode($_GET["json"]);
```

From javascript this reference will help you to get the parameter json from current url

[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

after get the json param you just need to

```
let json = getParam("json");
let data = JSON.parse(json);
```

getParam function you can create using above url. :)

Comment: I dont need to redirect it to the html page, I need to send a json response to the requesting server

Comment: You can use ajax or xhr request instead of standard post. standard post from html will redirect to target url or open in new tab. this will make things harder to passing result to HTML page.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the method $object->create() can only return true or false, I need a direct response like **echo json_encode(array("ID"=>"1"));** in my object.php

Comment: then just send `echo json_encode(array("ID"=>$this->conn->lastInsertId()));`

Comment: i'm not sure what is your problem. i hope you good luck with your case. :)